# Between query result from json array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I have json array look like this

```
        [
        {"hoteldetail":{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"500"},
        {"hoteldetail"{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"1200"},
        {"hoteldetail":{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"7000"},
        {"hoteldetail":{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"8000"}

        ]
```

From this i want to fetch the items with in a range of `minrate`

Eg: if the `minrate` range is (500,7500) it will returns the items from the json array that contains only the minrate with in the above range

So how can i get the output using `lodash`?

Comment: `_.filter(jsonArray, function(item) { return item.minrate>=500 && item.minrate<=7500; });`

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward implementation is

```
_.filter(arr, item => _.inRange(item.hoteldetail.minrate, 500, 7501))
```

which works exactly as it reads: filter the array for item whose property `hoteldetail.minrate` is within a specified range. However, newer lodash has a very nice function called `_.iteratee` which allows you to provide a filter shorthand, for example:

```
_.filter(arr, 'minrate in range 500, 7500')
```

Here is the implementation

```
_.iteratee = _.wrap(_.iteratee, function(callback, func) {
  var p = /minrate in range (\d+), (\d+)/g.exec(func);
  return !p ? callback(func) : function(object) {
    return object.hoteldetail.minrate >= p[1] && object.hoteldetail.minrate <= p[2];
  };
});
```

You can use this iteratee just like writing English `_.filter(arr, 'minrate in range 100, 200')`, `_.filter(arr, 'minrate in range 5000, 6000')`, etc. You can even go so far as to generalize `minrate` in the following manner:

```
_.iteratee = _.wrap(_.iteratee, function(callback, func) {
  var p = /(minrate|number\ of\ rooms) in range (\d+), (\d+)/g.exec(func);
  return !p ? callback(func) : function(object) {
    var prop = object.hoteldetail[p[1]];
    return prop >= p[2] && prop <= p[3];
  };
});
```

And use it as `_.filter(arr, 'number of rooms in range 1, 5')`

Doc: https://lodash.com/docs#iteratee

Comment: Getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: _.inRange is not a function`

Comment: @shammon what's your lodash version? `_.inRange` is very new. You can easily change it with your custom function though...

Comment: lodash Version 4.3.0

Comment: Yep i am sure abt that

Comment: What is the output when you just do `_.inRange(2, 1, 3)`?

Comment: Getting the same `_.inRange is not a function`

Comment: Then your lodash version is not 4.3.0. What is the output of `_.VERSION`?

Comment: the output of this is 4.3.0

Comment: okay try `_.filter(arr, item => item.hoteldetail.minrate >= 500 && item.hoteldetail.minrate <= 7500))`

Answer (score 0):

```
var _ = require('lodash'); //lodash 4.5
var hotels = [
    {"hoteldetail":{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"500"}},
    {"hoteldetail":{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"1200"}},
    {"hoteldetail":{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"7000"}},
    {"hoteldetail":{"hotelid":"00007111","hotelname":"hjghghg","minrate":"8000"}}
]
var filteredItems = _.filter(hotels, function(hotel){
    return _.inRange(hotel.hoteldetail.mitrate, 500, 7500);
});
```